# How to solve the equations $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}=bx^{2}+cxy+ay^{2}=d$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

This is from practice questions on quadratic equations in my book. I solved it in the following way:

Divide the equations by $x^2$

$\Longrightarrow c\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{2}+b\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+a\ =\frac{d}{x} ...(i)$

$\Longrightarrow a\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{2}+c\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+b\ =\frac{d}{x}...(ii)$

Subtract (ii) from (i) and by solving the resulting quadratic(by replacing $\frac{y}{x}$ with $t$) I get:

$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\left(c-b\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(b-c\right)^{2}-4\left(a-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}}{2(c-a)}$$

At this point I looked at the answer provided which was:

$x^2=y^2=d/a+b+c$ ;

$x/(c-a)=y/(a-b)=K$ where $K^2a(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-ab-bc-ca)=d$

**My question is where does this solution come from and if my approach is correct how to go further?**

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Thanks but how could it result in $x^2=y^2?, and I thought maybe there was a simpler approach

Comment: You have found $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\left(c-b\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(b-c\right)^{2}-4\left(a-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}}{2(c-a)}$, therefore $y = \frac{\left(c-b\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(b-c\right)^{2}-4\left(a-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}}{2(c-a)}x$, substitute this in one of the $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}=d$ or $bx^{2}+cxy+ay^{2}=d$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: I see you have wriiten the denominator wrong(its not 2a) after which you can proceed as stated by @K.K.McDonald.

Comment: Ok I will try that , @RamanujanXV yes  it should be 2(c-a) I will edit my question

Comment: Let $t=y/x$. When you obain the equation $(a-c)t^2+(c-b)t+b-a=0$, you must remark that 1 is an obvious root, so the other is $\frac{b-a}{a-c}$ (if $a\neq c$)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette Yes I see that now but thanks anyways

Comment: Why hide the fact that it's the four points (when defined; with multiplicity, over ${\Bbb C}$) $$(x,y) = (\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}},\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}})$$
$$(x,y) = (-\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}},-\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}})$$
$$(x,y) = ((a-c)\sqrt{\frac{d}{a(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)}},(b-a)\sqrt{\frac{d}{a(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)}})$$
$$(x,y) = (-(a-c)\sqrt{\frac{d}{a(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)}},-(b-a)\sqrt{\frac{d}{a(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)}})?$$ ($x^2=y^2=\frac{d}{a+b+c}$ taken alone is four points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You properly wrote$$t=\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\left(c-b\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(b-c\right)^{2}-4\left(a-b\right)\left(c-a\right)}}{2(c-a)}$$ but you did not notice that
$$\left(b-c\right)^{2}-4\left(a-b\right)\left(c-a\right)=(b+c-2 a)^2$$ which makes $t=1$ and $t=\frac{b-a}{a-c}$.

This should make the problem much more simple now.

Comment: Thanks I think this would give me the solution

Comment: Yes, plugging in $y=x$ or$y=(a-b)/(c-a)x$ gives the required solution, thanks so much :)